# How to aggregate and analyze input with logstash

Tags: logstash

I have some big files of log filled each 15 seconds with a heartbeat test result.
For example one of this file is like this :

```
2018-07-17 10:14:41.646166    TRACE    Service:Sales.API  Result:OK
2018-07-17 10:14:56.646166    TRACE    Service:Sales.API  Result:OK
2018-07-17 10:15:10.646166    TRACE    Service:Sales.API  Result:K0 >> KO I want to detect the
2018-07-17 10:15:24.646166    TRACE    Service:Sales.API  Result:OK
>> here some messages are missing : that I wan't to detect
2018-07-17 10:18:24.646166    TRACE    Service:Sales.API  Result:OK
```

For monitoring purpose I am only interested about KO result and detect if the heartbeat ping is not running :

I want to know if there is a known pattern to aggregate this input and produce at output a summary as follow :

- file1, purpose : "Detect KO result" :

  2018-07-17 10:15:10.646166    TRACE    Service:Sales.API  Result:K0

For this first file, I think I could use a filter to output a ko message.

- file2, purpose : "Detect heartbeat system fail to run" :

  from                           to                          level    service           message
    2018-07-17 10:15:24.646166   2018-07-17 10:18:24.646166  TRACE    Service:Sales.API  HeartBeat missed

For this second file I have played with the aggregate filter  but I do not know if it's doable with logstash Jruby code...

Answer (score 0):

Finding the "K0" message would be a straightforward pattern as you describe.

As for finding a gap in your messages, check out the [elapsed filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html).  If you can get the config correct, it should calculate the time between events, which should be exactly what you need.